# Fluent animation to follow the cursor

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I trying to figure out, how to create a smooth cursor follow animation with cocos2d js

Here some code:

```
var listener = cc.EventListener.create({
            event: cc.EventListener.MOUSE,
            onMouseMove: function (event) {
                var str = "MousePosition X: " + event.getLocationX() + "  Y:" + event.getLocationY();

                var actionBy = cc.MoveTo.create(2, cc.p(event.getLocationX(), $scope.bar._position.y));
                $scope.bar.stopAllActions();
                $scope.bar.runAction(
                    cc.sequence(
                        //cc.rotateTo(2, 0),
                        actionBy
                    )
                );


                // do something...
            }});
```

The problem here, its stuck because the event is fired to often and the "$scope.bar.stopAllActions();" stops the animation.

If I remove the "$scope.bar.stopAllActions();" the animation is driving crazy, the "bar" is flying over the screen.

I just wont the bar follow the mouse cursor, just like the dog follow human

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that if you remove `stopAllActions();` you'd be trying to run an action on an object that's already got an action of the same time. And in either case you are firing an animation too often on an object, I've rarely seen this work as expected.

I'd try running the action directly instead of putting it within a `cc.Sequence` first, but if that doesn't work, you've got two choices, both rely on manual labor:

a. Simply put the bar on the position of the mouse whenever it moves:
`$scope.bar.x = event.getLocationX();`

b. Assuming you want to "juice up" the game, just setting the bar on the mouse will be boring, so you could make the bar progressively catch up with the mouse:

In your constant section:

```
var EASING_CONSTANT = 0.9;
```

In the event handler:

```
$scope.bar.x += ($scope.bar.x - event.getLocationX()) * EASING_CONSTANT;
```

The lower your `EASING_CONSTANT` the slower the bar'll catch up to the mouse (only use values between 0 and 1).

Now, if you try to use this, you'll realize the bar never quite catches up with your mouse, so you'll have to place this code within an update function (in your main game layer's `update` method, for example) so it runs each frame.

BUT! Then you won't have access to an `event` object, so you'll have to end up with something like this:

In the event handler:

```
$scope.bar.targetX = event.getLocationX();
```

In the update method:

```
$scope.bar.x += ($scope.bar.x - $scope.bar.targetX) * EASING_CONSTANT;
```

There are lots of easing functions you can use, I just gave you the simplest example.

For instance, note that you also have the `event.getDeltaX()` method that'll return you the difference in position between the last call of the event and the current (how much the mouse moved since the last call of the event). With this you could do something along the lines of:

In your constant section:

```
var EASING_CONSTANT = 0.9;
var WOBBLING_CONSTANT = 10;
```

In the event handler:

```
$scope.bar.targetX = event.getLocationX();
$scope.bar.mouseDeltaX = event.getDeltaX();
```

In the update method:

```
$scope.bar.x += ($scope.bar.x - $scope.bar.targetX) * EASING_CONSTANT + Math.cos($scope.bar.mouseDeltaX) * WOBBLING_CONSTANT;
```

Just get creative and start messing around with the formula until you find a behaviour that "feels" right. But be sure to start simple first!

PS: I'm guessing you want your "bar" to only move on the x-axis, so.. are you making an arkanoid clone? :D